# How to send POST request to outlook 365 API to ReplyAll

Tags: c#, http-post, office365api

I am trying to ReplyAll to email with Outlook 365 API. Following [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#reply-or-reply-all-to-messages). As per tutorial to ReplyAll we just need to input `Commnet` but when I try to do that it's giving `Bad Request` error -

```
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidRecipients",
    "message": "At least one recipient isn't valid., A message can't be sent because it contains no recipients."
}
```

I am trying to do this with below method.

```
public string EmailReplyAll(AuthenticationResult result, string uriString, string msgBody)
{
 HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uriString);
 request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
 EmailReplyAll replyAll = new EmailReplyAll();
 replyAll.MsgBody = msgBody;
 var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgBody);
 var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
 HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(request.ToString(),content).Result;
 if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new WebException(response.StatusCode.ToString() + ": " + response.ReasonPhrase);
 uriString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 return uriString;
}
```

Could someone please point me where I am doing wrong. I'm trying this with WPF.

Comment: What is the value of uriString?

Comment: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/replyall

Comment: please check if you are passing the {message_id} correctly. Your error shows you are missing the recipients which I believe would something come from message_id that you post to.

Comment: @Souvik thank you for your pointer. I will give a try on it. Also could you tell me if we need to provide recipient and cc person to add to content of request or replyall uri will handle it?

Comment: Ideally it should be the ReplyAll Uri which will handle this. If you see the documentation there are no such parameters to pass recepients.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh Thanks for your input. I have figured out where I was wrong. Posting the working code in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I figured out and working for me.

**EmailReplyAll class**

```
public class EmailReplyAll
{
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

**The URI string -**

`var uriString = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}api/{1}/me/messages/{2}/replyall", graphApiEndpoint, graphApiVersion, emailId); 
//emailId is id of email e.g - AAMkADBjMGZiZGFACAAC8Emr9AAA=`

**EmailReplyAll method -**

```
public string EmailReplyAll(AuthenticationResult result, string uriString, string msgBody)
 {
  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
  EmailReplyAll replyAll = new EmailReplyAll();
  replyAll.Comment = msgBody;
  var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(replyAll);
  var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  try
   {
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(uriString, content).Result;
    var apiResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
    {
     return "Error";
    }       
     return apiResult;
 }
```